# SetOptions and Cell

Tags: options

I'm trying to change the CellLabel of Cells using

```
 SetOptions[Cell, CellLabel -> "test"]
```

or

```
 SetOptions[NotebookRead[nb], CellLabel -> "test"]
```

if nb is the notebook, without success. How should this be done?
Thanks, once again, for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what we are doing, use

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellLabel -> True]
```

Example:

```
Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"1", "+", "2"}]], "Input", 
  CellLabel -> "blabla"] // CellPrint
```

This should print a cell, such that you can see its label to the left of the cell.

Anyway, we can now do

```
SetOptions[#, CellLabel -> "test"] & /@ Cells[]
```

giving all `Cell`s CellLabel test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am now trying to the following:

Do[(
    NotebookWrite[nb, listOfCells[[i]]];
    SetOptions[listOfCells[i],CellLabel->"blabla";
),
{i, Length[listOfCells]}
]

where listOfCells is a list of cells read earlier from another document using DocumentRead[].

So, I'd like to add labels only in the new document, but not in the document from which these list of cells are read. How is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel no problem. Hm are you sure that you are using `DocumentRead`? I cannot find it in the docs. I think using `NotebookWrite` here is a bit tricky, as it does not always move the cursor in the right way. Instead of using `SetOptions` here, I suggest using something like `Append`, to set the option in the `Cell` expression. But maybe you should take care to remove any existing CellLabel option. Also I got `$Failed` a few times, maybe you should made it handle that case specially as well. Anyway, feel free to start a new Q&A about this :). Maybe I can then provide more details.

Comment: @ Jacob: sorry, I mistyped: I'm using NotebookRead!