# Append CellTag to list of Cells

Tags: notebooks, options

As suggested in [this earlier post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31949/setoptions-and-cell/31951?noredirect=1#comment99511_31951), I restate my question here about appending `CellTags` option to existing list of `Cells`.

What I have for the moment:

```
listOef = {};

SelectionMove[this, Before, Notebook];
SelectionMove[this, Next, Cell];
SelectionMove[this, Next, Cell];
Do[
 (
  SelectionMove[this, Next, CellGroup];
  AppendTo[listOef, NotebookRead[this]]
  )
  , {i, aantalVragen}]
```

This copies cells I give in the `EvaluationNotebook[]` to the list `listOef`.

I now want to write this list to the new notebook `nb` after permuting its elements randomly with

```
allPermutations = Table[RandomPermutation[aantalVragen], {aantalToetsen}];
```

like this:

```
 Do[
  (NotebookWrite[nb,
    Permute[listOef, allPermutations[[toetsNummer]]][[vraagNummer]]];
   ),
 {vraagNummer, aantalVragen}]
```

In this `Do[]` command, I would like to add Labels to every cell during the `NotebookWrite` command: its label would be `"vraagNummer"`, the counter which goes from `1` to `aantalVragen`, which is given at the beginning of the document.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
SetOptions[ Cell, CellLabel->"vraag"<>ToString[vraagNummer] ]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. How can I address the cell which has just been written by `NotebookWrite`? Or how would you suggest to do this using this structure?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer for this question:

```
NotebookSelection[nb]
```

gives the selected region of notebook nb. So using

```
SetOptions[NotebookSelection[nb], 
  CellLabel -> "Vraag " <> ToString[vraagNummer] <> "."];
```

this can indeed change the CellLabel after writing the cell.